# Maximum number of tables that can be used to create a view

Tags: database

Is there any limit on number of tables to be used to create a view? If there is a limit,then maximum how many no of tables we can use to create a view?

Comment: @skaffman, you added the sql-server tag, but it's not immediately clear that was the OPs RDBMS

Comment: @Paul: I changed it to "database"

Answer (score 2):

- 256, which the [maximum number of tables per select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx) statement SQL 2005
- [Limited by resources on SQL 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

I'd start worrying if you plan to get anywhere near this limit...

Comment: The reference provided on MSDN doesn't give a maximum it states "Tables per SELECT statement: Limited only by available resources"

Comment: @Nick, my mistake, must have misread or read the SQL 2005 page.

Comment: +1 for "I'd start worrying if you plan to get anywhere near this limit..."

Answer (score 2):

[In MySQL, it's 61](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/joins-limits.html)